# What is the problem with my code that it makes my resultant image of this particular image as jigsaw puzzles?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, image-enhancement

I am implementing a conference paper and it was originally in matlab and I translated it into python to process it with opencv using fuzzy contextual contrast enhancement method attached paper here in gdrive for reference.
[Research Paper Drive link open to all](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mA0bk72SfC3Kz2doKft61EcSbI7YtZcD/view?usp=sharing)

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('img1.bmp')
CIm = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

a=CIm[:,:,2]
Im = a/255
def f1(num):
    return math.floor(num*10000)
Im = np.vectorize(f1)(Im)

rows = Im.shape[0]
cols = Im.shape[1]

Ffactor = np.zeros(Im.shape,dtype = int)
H = np.zeros((10001,1),dtype=float)

w=1

width = round(np.std(Im.astype(float)))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        
        totf = 0.0
        count = 0 
        f = 0.0
        
        for ii in range(-w,w+1):
            for jj in range(-w,w+1):
                if (i + ii >= 0 and i + ii < rows and j + jj >= 0 and j + jj < cols):
                            count = count + 1 ;
                            temp = float(Im[i + ii,j + jj]) - float(Im[i,j])
                            f = max(min(1-abs(temp/width),1),0)
                            totf = totf + (f)
                            
        t =  totf/9
        print(count)
        Ffactor[i,j] = t
                
        H[Im[i,j]] = H[Im[i,j]] + math.log2(t)**2
Hpdf =  H/np.sum(H)
#total = np.sum(H)
#for k in range(H.shape[0]):
 #   Hpdf[k] = H[k]/total
    
    
def FHE(Im,Ffactor ,Hpdf, lval, hval):
    Hcdf = np.cumsum(Hpdf)
    m=np.mean(Im,dtype=float)
    s=np.std(Im,dtype=float)
    
    delta = s/m
    
    for i in range(Im.shape[0]):
        for j in range(Im.shape[1]):
            temp = lval + round(( hval- lval) * Hcdf[Im[i,j]] )
            Im[i,j] = ((temp - float(Im[i,j])) * math.exp((-(Ffactor[i,j])**2)*1*delta) + Im[i,j])
            
    return Im   

Imf = FHE(Im, Ffactor,Hpdf, 0, 10000)
Imf = Imf/10000
Imf = Imf*255
Imf = np.vectorize(round)(Imf)
CIm[:,:,2] = Imf;
Im_out = cv2.cvtColor(CIm, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('Original image',image)
cv2.imshow('equalised image', Im_out)
   
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5xk2.png)
[processed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM8Zv.png)

I don't get that why i am getting jigsaw puzzles in my processed image ??

I ran it with other pictures and it worked fine but with this particular picture it gives me this boxes everywhere and i can't figure out why ??
i was running original code of paper which was in matlab and it was better and worked fine without boxes.
I want to remove these boxes in my processed image pls check where fault lies in code.

Comment: One thought -- before dividing a by 255, be sure that you have converted a to float. Keep the processing as float until the end and then convert back to uint8.

Comment: Can you show the result image from matlab? If contrast in a quite constant region is maximized it could look similar.

Comment: Im_out may be out of the range 0 to 255. So check its min an max values and scale to the range 0 to 255 and convert to uint8.

Comment: @Micka [Matlab Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GSzAyZMGYyzfjjc93hmsDKuDw4GrHA7o/view?usp=sharing) This is the processed image through original code of the paper

Comment: @fmw42 I checked it maximum is 255 and minimum is 0 and i converted Im into float then converted it to uint8 at the end of processing

Comment: Did you convert 'a' to float before dividing by 255?